# Kartotherian Server Sources Configuration

Tags: postgis, server, vector-tiles

Is there any documentation for using Kartotherian Server with a vanilla/non OSM PostGIS database? 
The [Kartotherian core documentation](https://github.com/kartotherian/kartotherian-core) doesn't cover database connections or definitions of different parameters. [Tilelive](https://github.com/mapbox/tilelive) isn't too helpful either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [Mapbox Studio **Classic**](https://www.mapbox.com/help/getting-started-studio/), and create a new data source (tm2source) - write SQL queries in the studio - to pull that data into vector form, similar to how we do it in [WMF tm2source](https://github.com/kartotherian/osm-bright.tm2source/blob/master/data.yml)  Afterwards, create a new style (tm2) based on that data source, make sure the studio shows what you need, and point Kartotherian to both of these dirs - source1 (bridge) to tm2source, and source2 (vector) to tm2.  Your source config would be similar to [the sample](https://github.com/kartotherian/kartotherian/blob/master/sources.sample.yaml).  Mapbox studio classic uses the same components as Kartotherian, so if it works in one, it will work in the other.

Comment: I'm managing the data in PostGIS and the data can have upwards of a million records so I want to avoid shpfile conversion. Ideally I'd like to generate the XML files directly without the use of studio...Correct me if I'm wrong but I should be able to use the Mapnik documentation to figure out how to define the XML right?

Comment: ah, sorry, I thought you meant you didn't want to use postgis at all :)   Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but my files seem to be too big for MapBox Studio. For large files Studio gets rid of half the features and turns polygons into triangles. Any advice? Should I be using something like Tippecanoe for large files?

Comment: Files? I thought all your data is in SQL database? If you mean that the resultset is too large for each tile, you might need to use filtering and optimization, such as bbox filter, polygon simplification, etc. Mapbox studio should not simplify geoahapes for you -- your sql would usually do that.

Comment: Sorry, yes the SQL result set, it seems like Studio was just taking very long to render the geometry so shapes appeared simplified. Trying the process again worked. I haven't tried the tm2 process yet but I'll look into it shortly.

Comment: It seems you need to optimize your SQL query - use `way && !bbox!` where clause, as well as something like `z(!scale_denominator!) >= 14` for zoom level filtering.  For example, see https://github.com/kartotherian/osm-bright.tm2source/blob/master/data.yml#L96

Comment: thanks for the help, but I created a solution for creating mbtiles that seems more suited to my needs (I used python to export PostGIS data into GeoJSON and then use tippecanoe to create mbtiles from large combinations of data). Using MapBox Studio is too manual for my needs.